# Display queryset count sitewide?

Tags: python, django

What is the best way to display a query set count site wide? instead of calling `users` in every view.

Example:

views.py

```py
def index(request):
    users = Profile.objects.all().count()
    return render(request, 'layout.html', {'users': users})
```

layout.html

```py
<P>Total Users: ({{users}})</P>
```

Comment: What does this have to do with django-rest-framework exactly ??? (tag removed).

Comment: What should display if a new user open an account?

Comment: Have you setup a base.html? Please provide more code, its not clear right now what you have done exactly

Comment: It only displays on the homepage because you only pass the variable `users` into the context in your index-view. See the answers below on how to always get `users`  into the context.

Comment: yeah i know but i don't wanna pass `users` var into every view. I just used a custom template tag, working now. thanks

Answer (score -3, accepted):

You want [a custom template tag](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/howto/custom-template-tags). The documentation is clear enough so that there's no need for an example here.

Answer (score 0):

This looks like you need a [custom context_processor](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/templates/api/#writing-your-own-context-processors). Then you have `users` in the context for every request/view.

Comment: Context processors are invoked for each and every **template rendering** (not "request/view"), whether they are needed or not. One should restrict their use to cheap operations (reading a setting etc), and avoid database queries and any potentially complex / costly operation. Also they are quite implicit and having template vars popping out from nowhere doesn't help wrt maintainability. The best choice here is a custom template tag - only invoked when needed, and perfectly explicit.

Comment: Since the count is displayed on every page (in the footer) a context_processor is doing the same amount of work as it would do a template_tag for this purpose. If he puts the template_tag into the footer and decides he wants to show it somewhere else there are more operations than would be with a context_processor. At the end its the users choice with method fits best.

Comment: please re-read the emphasised part of my comment (ok, it's a bit wrong: context processors are invoked for every template rendering _using a RequestContext_ - but that's still much more than "for every request/view", think of all inclusion tags etc).